# How to use Word2Vec for classification problem in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to predict big 5 personality traits (Extraversion, Neuroticism,  Agreeableness,  Conscientiousness, Openness) based on text analysis written by user. 
Here is my preprocessed data set:

[image: df_processed]

And here is my word2vec model:

```
model_wv = Word2Vec(df_processed['TEXT'], sg=1, size=300, window=10, min_count=1)
```

Vocabulary consists of 26126 words.

```
features = ['cEXT', 'cNEU', 'cAGR', 'cCON', 'cOPN']
X = df_processed['TEXT']
y = df_processed[features]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.3,random_state=101)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 100)) 
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

My question is, how can I use word2vec vectors in tensorflow model?

Should I replace every word in every row in "X" with the vector from word2vec model? I think it will be quite expensive for calculation but what will be another possibility?

Sorry if my questions sounds dummy, I' m just really new in NLP and tensorflow.

Comment: Can you tell us why you think having vector per word would be expensive? The cost would depend on the length of the text you have. How long are these on average?

Comment: @thushv89, On average there are 250 words in every text.